# mac os x 10.9.4 install jdk5

Tags: java, macos, installation, java-5

hi, all:
         I have some trouble in installing jdk5 on os x 10.9.4, I couldn't find the install file in oralce website and the apple developer site, how could i install jdk5 on os x 10.9.4?
    
    thank you in advance.
    
    Updated: I used the script in github: [install script](https://gist.github.com/hansenc/7234566) , but it was 32 bit...I need 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Prior to Java 7, Apple managed the Java JRE/JDK.  It came pre-installed (or auto-installed on first time use).  With Apple's Java implementation, you have no choice over which version to install -- a version of OS X will be able to install a certain version of Java and no other.  I'm not sure what the last version of OS X to run Java 5 was, but certainly 10.9 Mavericks uses Java 6.

In OS X 10.9, your only choices are Apple's Java 6 (auto-installed on first time use) or Oracle's Java 7 (downloaded form Oracle's website).  This applies to both the JRE and JDK.